# Chosen добавить option

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
  $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-placeholder=" " class="chosen-select" id="organization" name="organization" multiple>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Название организации">Название организации</option>
  <option value="Название организации 1">Название организации 1</option>
  <option value="Название организации 2">Название организации 2</option>
  <option value="Название организации 3">Название организации 3</option>
  <option value="Название организации 4">Название организации 4</option>
  <option value="Название организации 5">Название организации 5</option>
</select>
```

Вопрос в следующем, как можно сделать так, если в select нету option при поиске и выборе из списка, добавлять новый option из того, что ввели в строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя из [документации](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) chosen - он так не умеет. Я бы посоветовал похожую библиотеку [Select2](https://select2.org/), она позволяет это сделать через [теги](https://select2.org/tagging) (так они это называют).
Вот пример в действии:

```js
$(".form-control").select2({
  width: '100px',
  tags: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>
```